# Float and Double value creating confusion in c

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, double

I am running this program. But getting strange result.

```
int  main()
{
float a=.8;
if(a < .8)
    printf("a is small\n");
else
    printf("a is not small\n");

float b=.7;
if(b < .7)
    printf("b is small\n");
else
    printf("b is not small\n");
return 0;
}
```

It gives me output--

> a is not small
>
> b is small

Comment: Please look for duplicates of this. There are hundreds.

Comment: I wonder how people represent a floating point number using bits

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `0.7f`. `0.7` Is by default `double`, so we cannot predict it's behaviour